# Como concatenar colunas identificadas pelo apelido?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql, concatenação-de-string

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
select case when datediff(...) > 0 then month(tblData.data1)
            when day(tblData.data2) > 10 then month(tblData.data2)
            when month(tblData.data2) = 1 then 12 
            else month(tblData.data2) - 1 end as Mês,

    case when datediff(...) > 0 then year(tblData.data1)
    when day(tblData.data2) > 10 then year(tblData.data2)
    when month(tblData.data2) = 1 then year(tblData.data2) - 1 
    else year(tblData.data2) end as Ano,

    concat(Ano, Mês) as AnoMes -- Como fazer essa linha aqui funcionar??

...
from where order by
```

Eu preciso que a terceira coluna concatene os valores das duas anteriores. Porém, se eu colocar essa função tomo um erro de nome de coluna não definido, visto que `Ano`e `Mês` são apenas apelidos.

- Como posso concatenar esses valores evitando a repetição desses `case when`???

---

> obs: as partes omitidas em nada interferem com a questão!

Comment: não é possível referenciar um alias na mesma query, porque isso é processado ao final, e no momento da execução "Mês" não existe, só vai ser ao final da query. A solução pra isso é transformar o primeiro case num subselect

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível dessa forma. Mesmo que suas colunas com apelido venham antes, não é assim que as coisas funcionam...

Esse trecho de código por exemplo:

```
case when datediff(...) > 0 then month(tblData.data1)
            when day(tblData.data2) > 10 then month(tblData.data2)
            when month(tblData.data2) = 1 then 12 
            else month(tblData.data2) - 1 end as Mês
```

Ainda não foi processado no contexto da sua consulta, logo esse apelido "Mês" não existe ainda. Não é tão simples como um excel por exemplo, pra acessar essa informação ela precisa ser processada primeiro.

Para não repetir esse processamento, você pode fazer um `SELECT` ao redor da sua consulta, transformando a consulta principal em uma `SUB-QUERY`.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT mês 
  FROM (SELECT CASE
                 WHEN datediff(.. .) > 0 THEN MONTH(tbldata.data1)
                 WHEN DAY(tbldata.data2) > 10 THEN MONTH(tbldata.data2)
                 WHEN MONTH(tbldata.data2) = 1 THEN 12
                 ELSE MONTH(tbldata.data2) - 1
               END AS mês
          FROM tblData)
```

Assim a coluna mês já foi processada na sua sub consulta e você poderá fazer o que quiser com ela na consulta principal sem repetir o processamento.

Você poderia ainda criar uma visão para sua tabela, retornando esses campos formatados e utiliza-la na sua consulta... As formas de se fazer isso são várias...